# MySQLi foreach bind_param()

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm sending an array of values from a form. I want to loop through the database table looking for these IDs. As I get this message I understand something is wrong...

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in  /home/d15155/tool/pdf.php on line 56

```
if (count($_POST['q']) == 0){
}
else {
  foreach($_POST['q'] as $quality){
    # Prepare statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT the_question, the_sub_questions, the_quality, the_time FROM my_questions WHERE the_category='2' AND the_headline='5' AND quality_id = ? ORDER BY the_sort_order ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $quality);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($the_question, $the_sub_questions, $the_quality, $the_time); 
    $stmt->fetch();
    $konkretaexempel .= utf8_encode($the_question) . " <br />";
  }
}
```

I want to add the results into a long string (then to be used in a PDF).

**EDIT**

Removed the foreach and the array and it still getting the same error message. I have checked and the database connection is OK.

```
    if (count($_POST['q']) == 0){

    }
    else {

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT the_question, the_sub_questions, the_quality, the_time FROM my_questions WHERE the_category='2' AND the_headline='5' AND quality_id = ? ORDER BY the_sort_order ASC");

        $stmt->bind_param('i', '27');
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($the_question, $the_sub_questions, $the_quality, $the_time); 
        $stmt->fetch();
        $konkretaexempel .= utf8_encode($the_question) . " <br />";

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you truncated the error message; You may want to edit your question to include the full message.

Comment: It means `prepare` didn't work. Try to add \` aroung column names in your statement

Comment: side note: the purpose of `->prepare()` is so that you don't need to call it on each loop iteration. By placing it inside your `foreach()` you are wasting one of its best function/feature.

Answer (score 1):

Sean's tip in the comments is probably more than a side note here; it will get rid off the problem: There can be only one active query/statement per connection and after the single ->fetch() the statement is still active (a while-loop would fix that, but no need for that here). When you re-use the $stmt instance as suggested any old result set will be discarded.

Your script currently is like

```
<?php
$mysqli = setup();

if (count($_POST['q']) == 0){
    myErrorHandling();
}
else {
    foreach($_POST['q'] as $quality){       
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT x, y FROM soFoo WHERE id = ?");
        if ( !$stmt ) { die('prepare failed'); }
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $quality);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($x, $y); 
        $stmt->fetch();
        printf("x=%d,y=%s\r\n", $x, $y);
    }
}


function setup() {
    // for demonstration purposes only
    $_POST = [ 'q'=> [
        1,3,5
    ]];

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');


    $mysqli->query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment,
            x int,
            y varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (x,y) VALUES (?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $x, $y);
    foreach( range('a','z') as $x=>$y ) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    return $mysqli;
}
```

and the output is

```
x=0,y=a
prepare failed
```

Now when I move the calls to prepare/bind_param to before the loop

```
<?php
$mysqli = setup();

if (count($_POST['q']) == 0){
    myErrorHandling();
}
else {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT x, y FROM soFoo WHERE id = ?");
    if ( !$stmt ) { die('prepare failed'); }
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $quality);
    foreach($_POST['q'] as $quality){       
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($x, $y); 
        $stmt->fetch();
        printf("x=%d,y=%s\r\n", $x, $y);
    }
}


function setup() {
  ... same as before...
}
```

the output is

```
x=0,y=a
x=2,y=c
x=4,y=e
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply VolkerK, I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same error message. I tried creating a new array just for testing purpose but still same error.

Comment: I've tested those scripts with php 5.6.10/win32 and mysql 5.6.something

Comment: Hmm.. I tested without the foreach and the array now and still getting the same error... Please See original post.